# Internet not working on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, wireless, networking

Suddenly internet stopped working on my ubuntu 13.04 system. First i tried restarting router but it didn't worked. Then i tried internet on `WIN 7` it is working fine.
But it is not working on ubuntu,I have tried both LAN/Wifi but they are not working.
Below i have pasted all the information i gathered:

```
iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

eth1      IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:21:9b:f3:c7:39  
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::221:9bff:fef3:c739/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1298 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1429 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:357699 (357.6 KB)  TX bytes:150796 (150.7 KB)
          Interrupt:16 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:23:4d:4d:4a:0b  
          inet6 addr: fe80::223:4dff:fe4d:4a0b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:17 Base address:0xc000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1916 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1916 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:133301 (133.3 KB)  TX bytes:133301 (133.3 KB)


ping 8.8.8.8 -c 4
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=1 ttl=56 time=28.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=2 ttl=56 time=27.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=3 ttl=56 time=27.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=4 ttl=56 time=36.4 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 27.436/29.997/36.444/3.731 ms


 ping www.google.com -c 4
ping: unknown host www.google.com


 ping 192.168.1.1 -c 4
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.610 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.588 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=0.554 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=4 ttl=64 time=0.575 ms

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 2997ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.554/0.581/0.610/0.035 ms


sudo apt-get update
Err http://archive.scrapy.org precise Release.gpg                                                                                      
  Something wicked happened resolving 'archive.scrapy.org:http' (-11 - System error)
Err http://archive.canonical.com raring Release.gpg                                                                                    
  Something wicked happened resolving 'archive.canonical.com:http' (-11 - System error)
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release.gpg                                                                                        
  Something wicked happened resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net:http' (-11 - System error)



sudo lshw
ubuntu
    description: Portable Computer
    product: Inspiron 1525 ()
    vendor: Dell Inc.
    serial: F7VH2BS
    width: 32 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.4 dmi-2.4
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=portable uuid=44454C4C-3700-1056-8048-C6C04F324253
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 0U990C
       vendor: Dell Inc.
       physical id: 0
       serial: .F7VH2BS.CN7016689U0NZW.
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Dell Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: A17
          date: 10/27/2009
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 1984KiB
          capabilities: isa pci pcmcia pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect int13floppy720 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb agp smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T5800  @ 2.00GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 400
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: 6.15.13
          serial: 0000-06FD-0000-0000-0000-0000
          slot: Microprocessor
          size: 800MHz
          capacity: 2GHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 200MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm dtherm cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 id=0 threads=2
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 700
             size: 32KiB
             capacity: 32KiB
             capabilities: internal write-back data
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 701
             size: 2MiB
             capacity: 2MiB
             clock: 66MHz (15.0ns)
             capabilities: pipeline-burst internal varies unified
        *-logicalcpu:0
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 0.1
             width: 64 bits
             capabilities: logical
        *-logicalcpu:1
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 0.2
             width: 64 bits
             capabilities: logical
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 1000
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 2GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM DDR Synchronous 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
             product: HYMP112S64CP6-S6
             vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
             physical id: 0
             serial: 04008132
             slot: DIMM_A
             size: 1GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 800MHz (1.2ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM DDR Synchronous 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
             product: HYMP112S64CP6-S6
             vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
             physical id: 1
             serial: 04008054
             slot: DIMM_B
             size: 1GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 800MHz (1.2ns)
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 Memory Controller Hub
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 0c
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=agpgart-intel
          resources: irq:0
        *-display:0
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary)
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 0c
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:45 memory:fea00000-feafffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:eff8(size=8)
        *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
             description: Display controller
             product: Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary)
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
             version: 0c
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:feb00000-febfffff
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:20 ioport:6f20(size=32)
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.1
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:21 ioport:6f00(size=32)
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a.7
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.7
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:22 memory:fed1c400-fed1c7ff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 02
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:46 memory:fe9fc000-fe9fffff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:40 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:fe800000-fe8fffff ioport:80000000(size=2097152)
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
                logical name: eth0
                version: 12
                serial: 00:21:9b:f3:c7:39
                size: 100Mbit/s
                capacity: 100Mbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2 driverversion=1.30 duplex=full ip=192.168.1.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
                resources: irq:44 memory:fe8fc000-fe8fffff ioport:de00(size=256)
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.1
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:41 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:fe700000-fe7fffff ioport:80200000(size=2097152)
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY
                vendor: Broadcom Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0
                logical name: eth1
                version: 01
                serial: 00:23:4d:4d:4a:0b
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.20.155.1 (r326264) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
                resources: irq:17 memory:fe7fc000-fe7fffff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 5
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.4
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:42 ioport:c000(size=4096) memory:fe400000-fe6fffff ioport:f0000000(size=2097152)
        *-usb:3
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:20 ioport:6f80(size=32)
        *-usb:4
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.1
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:21 ioport:6f60(size=32)
        *-usb:5
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.2
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:22 ioport:6f40(size=32)
        *-usb:6
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.7
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.7
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:20 memory:fed1c000-fed1c3ff
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1e
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1e.0
             version: f2
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
             resources: memory:fe300000-fe3fffff
           *-firewire
                description: FireWire (IEEE 1394)
                product: R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller
                vendor: Ricoh Co Ltd
                physical id: 9
                bus info: pci@0000:02:09.0
                version: 05
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm ohci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=firewire_ohci latency=64 maxlatency=4 mingnt=2
                resources: irq:16 memory:fe3ff800-fe3fffff
           *-generic:0
                description: SD Host controller
                product: R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter
                vendor: Ricoh Co Ltd
                physical id: 9.1
                bus info: pci@0000:02:09.1
                version: 22
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=sdhci-pci latency=64
                resources: irq:18 memory:fe3ff400-fe3ff4ff
           *-generic:1
                description: System peripheral
                product: R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter
                vendor: Ricoh Co Ltd
                physical id: 9.2
                bus info: pci@0000:02:09.2
                version: 12
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=r592 latency=64
                resources: irq:18 memory:fe3ff600-fe3ff6ff
           *-generic:2
                description: System peripheral
                product: xD-Picture Card Controller
                vendor: Ricoh Co Ltd
                physical id: 9.3
                bus info: pci@0000:02:09.3
                version: 12
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=r852 latency=64
                resources: irq:18 memory:fe3ff700-fe3ff7ff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: 82801HM (ICH8M) LPC Interface Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-ide
             description: IDE interface
             product: 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) IDE Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.1
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: ide bus_master
             configuration: driver=ata_piix latency=0
             resources: irq:16 ioport:1f0(size=8) ioport:3f6 ioport:170(size=8) ioport:376 ioport:6fa0(size=16)
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:43 ioport:6eb0(size=8) ioport:6eb8(size=4) ioport:6ec0(size=8) ioport:6ec8(size=4) ioport:6ee0(size=32) memory:fe9fb800-fe9fbfff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:fe9fb700-fe9fb7ff ioport:10c0(size=32)
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 1
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: WDC WD1600BEVT-7
             vendor: Western Digital
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: 11.0
             serial: WD-WXE808SV0853
             size: 149GiB (160GB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=512 signature=70000000
           *-volume:0
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: Dell 8.0
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                version: FAT16
                serial: 07d8-0a13
                size: 117MiB
                capacity: 117MiB
                capabilities: primary fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat label=DellUtility
           *-volume:1
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                version: 3.1
                serial: 5c89718e-6480-cd49-b364-ef9b33d13654
                size: 10216MiB
                capacity: 10239MiB
                capabilities: primary ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2013-04-03 14:01:34 filesystem=ntfs label=New Volume state=clean
           *-volume:2
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                version: 3.1
                serial: 0c39-c2bc
                size: 78MiB
                capacity: 100MiB
                capabilities: primary bootable ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2012-06-25 16:12:32 filesystem=ntfs label=System Reserved state=clean
           *-volume:3
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 4
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,4
                logical name: /dev/sda4
                logical name: /host
                version: 3.1
                serial: 40c0874d-f90c-a443-b48e-9cf8fe425595
                size: 138GiB
                capacity: 138GiB
                capabilities: primary ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2012-06-25 16:12:47 filesystem=ntfs mount.fstype=fuseblk mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096 state=mounted
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 2
          logical name: scsi3
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: DVD+-RW GSA-T21N
             vendor: HL-DT-ST
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/cdrw
             logical name: /dev/dvd
             logical name: /dev/dvdrw
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: A1R1
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=open
  *-battery
       product: DELL X409G8A
       physical id: 1
       slot: Sys. Battery Bay
       capacity: 37000mWh
       configuration: voltage=11.1V
```

Can someone please help me

Comment: Open terminal and give a try to these commands one after another: `sudo dhclient eth0` : if you are using cabled connection.   `sudo dhclient eth1` or `sudo dhclient wlan0` : if you are connected via wireless. Reply what happens..

Comment: `sudo dhclient eth1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists

` This is what i got from this command ....

Comment: It was long suggestion, so wrote as an answer..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether it will work or not but you can give it a try. It is safe so no need to worry.

Follow these steps.

- First take a backup of `/etc/network/interfaces`

  ```
  sudo cp /etc/network/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces.back
  ```
- Open `/etc/network/interfaces` by `sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces` and replace the contents with this:

  ```
  auto eth1
  iface eth1 inet dhcp
  ```
- Save and close `gedit`and execute following command:

  ```
  sudo ifup eth1
  ```
- Try to connect again, also try to restart you system once.
- If it doesn't work then I am sorry! this would not be your solution. Replace your new `/etc/network/interfaces` file with old one: `/etc/network/interfaces.back`:

  ```
  sudo mv /etc/network/interfaces.back /etc/network/interfaces
  ```

Reply what happens.

Comment: It didn't worked ... it has something to do with name server.. because when i used `mtr` to ping `8.8.8.8` it said `Resolver: Received error response 5. (refused by name server) ....